# Multiple sfdc sessions in one http session

Tags: session

Can multiple access_tokens (salesforce sessionId's) be used on a single HTTP connection?

Goal is to manage access tokens (fetched via oauth user/password flow on behalf of the end user) on ESB. Then when a request is initiated by end user via an application connected to the ESB, the ESB will inject te token in http authorization header and reuse an http connection towards sfdc from the pool. So during the lifetime of the http connection multiple different access token (in fact sfdc sessionids) will be passed through it.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by doing this?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase. Goal is to manage access tokens (fetched via oauth user/password flow on behalf of the end user) on ESB. Then when a request is initiated by end user via an application connected to the ESB, the ESB will inject te token in http authorization header and reuse an http connection towards sfdc from the pool. So during the lifetime of the http connection multiple different access token (in fact sfdc sessionids) will be passed through it.

Comment: I've never thought about it, but I think this is actually a pretty interesting question. Unless someone beats me to it, I'll see if I can set up an experiment.